# Outlook flickering on adding too much recipients to "To" field when composing a new e-mail

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in. In compose windows, every time a recipient is added to the "To" field, I iterate over all the recipients to search for some recipients not satisfying a particular condition. I add the ones that do not comply some rules to a List of strings. This list contains the displays names or e-mail addresses of the recipients that didn't comply the rules (I am not creating a list of Outlook COM objects).

I have noticed that the more recipients I add to the "To" field, the more slow Outlook it is by processing all them. I don't know what is Outlook internally doing for each recipient but I can see each of them are underlined maybe because they are resolved fine for Outlook, I don't know. During this process I can see that the "To" field is flickering too much.

Why is it happening? The culprit is my VSTO Add-in or the Outlook itself that it is not able to process well too much recipients and it has difficulties.

I simply do this:

```
List<string> recipientsNotSatisfyingCondition = new List<string>();

Outlook.Recipients recipients = this.MyMailItem?.Recipients;

try 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= recipients.Count; i++)
    {
        Outlook.Recipient recipient = recipients[i];

        if (recipient_does_not_complains_some_rules)
        {
            recipientsNotSatisfyingCondition.Add(recipient.Name ?? recipient.Address);
        }

        if (recipient != null) 
        {
            Marshall.ReleaseComObject(recipient);
            recipient = null;
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // Log error
}
finally
{
    if (recipients != null)
    {
        Marshall.ReleaseComObject(recipients);
        recipients = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you simply loop through through all recipients? What about looping and accessing only the Name property?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yeap, I am observing the same problem if I only loop through all recipients and do nothing.

Comment: Do you do that immediately in the event handler or at some later point?

Comment: What is your condition `recipient_does_not_complains_some_rules`? Which properties of the `Recipient` class do you use there?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have an event handler that catches when Outlook.MailItem property is changed. That event handler is subscribed to Outlook.MailItem.PropertyChange so when some property of the Outlook.MailItem is changed, it raises (in this case "To" field). In this event handler a timer is enabled, MyTimer.Enabled = true; and after timer is enablend, a few second later MyTimer_Tick event handler is raised. From within the event handler MyTimer_Tick then I call a method and this method does the loop i commented, i mean, it iterates over all the recipients.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev recipient_does_not_compalin_some_rules check for the recipient in question if i have some data in a temporary data structure I have, i don't consult any outlook property there, only custom data i have for each recipient. But anyway, not doing this check out and only iterate over all recipients in the loop without checking if rules are satisfied or not, the problem is still noticeable. i have commented all the code and only leave the loop iterating over all recipients and it continues happing, flickering.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good. But I'd suggest calling the [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall) method which attempts to resolve all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book before iterating over all recipients in the collection and getting the `Address` property.

Comment: why do you suggest to better call Recipients.ResolveAll method before attempting to iterate over all recipients? maybe to ensure the all the e-mail addresses are valid?

Answer (score 0):

On the Extended MAPI level, there is no "recipient" object - recipients are stored in an `IMAPITable` object (`IMessage::GetRecipientTable`) that stores all recipients, and the whole table can be retrieved in a single call using `IMAPITable::QueryRows` or `HrQueryAllRows`. That would require Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), but the bigger problem is that you are working with a new message that might not be saved yet and the changes made on the OOM or Outlook UI level are not yet committed to the underlying MAPI object (`IMessage`). You can call `MailItem.Save` before retrieving `IMessage` object from `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT` and recipients using `IMessage::GetRecipientTable` / `HrQueryAllRows`, but saving the message might be undesirable.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) is an option, you can bypass OOM (and thus eliminate the flickering) using [SafeMailItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeMailItem.htm) object. It also exposes `Commit` method that forces Outlook to commit the data to the `IMessage` object without saving it in the Drafts folder and preserves the item's dirty state.

As a quick test, does the following script cause flickering? You can run it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am also its author) - open a draft message with a large number of recipients, click Script button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, paste the script, click Run:

```vb
set sItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
sItem.Item = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
sItem.Commit 'commit changes to MAPI without saving the message
for each recip in sItem.Recipients
  Debug.Print recip.Address
next
```